# Add contact if contact does not exist under google contacts with “ContactsApp.getContact”

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-contacts-api

I found the following code as a response to the same question at [Check if contact exists under google contacts with "ContactsApp.getContact"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63265976/check-if-contact-exists-under-google-contacts-with-contactsapp-getcontact#new-answer) but am having some trouble. I am trying to create a Google Script that checks to see if a respondent to a Google Survey already has a contact card in 'System Group: My Contacts' and if not, create a contact card and then add their phone number.

I've updated the following code to reference my fields, but am receiving an error for the line    `if(emailjson[email.toLowerCase()].id)` - which is meant to check to see if that contact existed:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "id" from undefined. (line 36, file "Code")

I thought that there was a problem with the IF statement, but I'm not completely familiar with Javascript (or JSON). As an Excel and Access person I'm accustomed to IF statements having a IF something is null, then do this, which so I tried adding `=== undefined`, changing the code to `if(emailjson[email.toLowerCase()].id === undefined)` but that didn't solve the problem. In looking at the Execution Transcript, it hangs up as soon as it hits someone who doesn't have a contact card.

If I remove new contacts from the beginning of my spreadsheet and go back to the original code (without `=== undefined`), then it creates duplicate contact cards for everyone who already had a card to start with until it reaches the next person who is new, and then it errors out again.

For the people who already have contact cards, I've also received an error on the next line if the phone number in the spreadsheet is just numbers, `if(!emailjson[email.toLowerCase()]['phones'][phone.replace(/[_)(\s.-]/g,'')]) {`.

> TypeError: Cannot find function replace in object 2024313437. (line 37, file "Code")

If I add formatting to the phone number, then it doesn't throw an error (although as I mentioned before, it creates a duplicate contact). Oddly, I I run the function emailsasJSON afterwards, it only shows one contact card as opposed to a duplicate card, even though on the Google Contacts screen I see a contact card for every time I've attempted to run the script.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

```
function emailsasJSON() {
  
 var emailjson = {}
  var myContacts = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('System Group: My Contacts').getContacts();
  for (var i = 0; i < myContacts.length; i++) {
    var emails = myContacts[i].getEmails();
    var phonesobj = myContacts[i].getPhones();
    var phones = {}
    for (var j = 0; j < phonesobj.length; j++) {
       phones[phonesobj[j].getPhoneNumber().replace(/[_)(\s.-]/g,'')] = 1;
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < emails.length; j++) {
      emailjson[emails[j].getAddress().toLowerCase()] = {id: myContacts[i].getId(), phones:  phones};
      
    }
  }
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(emailjson))
  return emailjson;
}

function addClient() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheetNew = ss.getActiveSheet(); 

 var clientsgroup = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('System Group: My Contacts')

//this is where we will insert the function from above to get the emailjson obj
 var emailjson = emailsasJSON()

 var contactarray = sheetNew.getDataRange().getValues();
 for (var i = 1 ; i < contactarray.length; i++){
   var name = contactarray[i][1]
   var email = contactarray[i][4]
   var phone = contactarray[i][3]
   
   if(emailjson[email.toLowerCase()].id) { //check if email exists
     if(!emailjson[email.toLowerCase()]['phones'][phone.replace(/[_)(\s.-]/g,'')]) { //if email exists but phone doesn't, add phone
         
     ContactsApp.getContactById(emailjson[email.toLowerCase()].id).addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE, phone)
     emailjson[email.toLowerCase()]['phones'][phone.replace(/[_)(\s.-]/g,'')] = 1; //add it to the emailjson object in case there are more iterations of this contact in the sheet
     } 
   } else { //add new contact if it doesn't exist
   
    var newcontact = ContactsApp.createContact(name.split(' ')[0],name.split(' ')[1], email)
    newcontact.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE, phone)
    emailjson[email.toLowerCase()]['id'] = newcontact.getId();
    emailjson[email.toLowerCase()]['phones'][phone.toString().replace(/[_)(\s.-]/g,'')] = 1;
    clientsgroup.addContact(newcontact)
     }
  }
}
```

Sample Data:[image: Contact Card]

[image: Spreadsheet]

Comment: Can you add examples for the values in your google sheet and contacts group?

Comment: What do you get if you log both emailjson and the email array ```Logger.log(emailjson, emailjosn[email.toLowercase()].id)```?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf - `Logger.log(emailjson,emailjson[emails.toLowerCase()].id)` returns 
> TypeError: Cannot find function toLowerCase in object EmailField. 

If I remove `.toLowerCase()` then I get a 

> TypeError: Cannot read property "id" from undefined. (line 18, file "Code")

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe - added sample data as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that your function `emailsasJSON()` stringified the json object (i.e it was a string) and therefore you could not access successfully the key pair values of the JSON object. To solve this I just parsed the object to make sure it was consistent but as long as you wouldn't have converted it into a string it would have been ok.

The next change is in the first if condition. You don't actually need to check for the id to see if the element exists as just by checking the element itself would do the job (although checking the id would work too).

Finally the way you constructed your json object for the new contact was not done correctly so I have corrected it accordingly to add the appropriate key value pairs.

```js
function emailsasJSON() {
  
 var emailjson = {}
  var myContacts = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('System Group: My Contacts').getContacts();
  for (var i = 0; i < myContacts.length; i++) {
    var emails = myContacts[i].getEmails();
    var phonesobj = myContacts[i].getPhones();
    var phones = {}
    for (var j = 0; j < phonesobj.length; j++) {
       phones[phonesobj[j].getPhoneNumber().replace(/[_)(\s.-]/g,'')] = 1;
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < emails.length; j++) {
      emailjson[emails[j].getAddress().toLowerCase()] = {id: myContacts[i].getId(), phones:  phones};
      
    }
  }
  emailjson = JSON.stringify(emailjson);
  emailjson = JSON.parse(emailjson);
  return emailjson;
}

function addClient() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheetNew = ss.getActiveSheet(); 

 var clientsgroup = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('System Group: My Contacts')

//this is where we will insert the function from above to get the emailjson obj
 var emailjson = emailsasJSON()

 var contactarray = sheetNew.getDataRange().getValues();
 for (var i = 1 ; i < contactarray.length; i++){
   var name = contactarray[i][1]
   var email = contactarray[i][4]
   var phone = contactarray[i][3]
   
   
   
   if(emailjson[email.toLowerCase()]) { //check if email exists
     if(!emailjson[email.toLowerCase()]['phones'][phone.toString().replace(/[_)(\s.-]/g,'')]) { //if email exists but phone doesn't, add phone
     ContactsApp.getContactById(emailjson[email.toLowerCase()].id).addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE, phone)
     emailjson[email.toLowerCase()]['phones'][phone.toString().replace(/[_)(\s.-]/g,'')] = 1; //add it to the emailjson object in case there are more iterations of this contact in the sheet
     }
   } else { //add new contact if it doesn't exist
    var newcontact = ContactsApp.createContact(name.split(' ')[0],name.split(' ')[1], email);
     var newContactId = newcontact.getId();
     var phoneNumber = phone.toString().replace(/[_)(\s.-]/g,'');
     ContactsApp.getContactById(newContactId).addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE, phone);
     emailjson[email.toLowerCase()] = {id:newContactId,phones:{phoneNumber : 1}}
     clientsgroup.addContact(newcontact)
     }
  }
}
```

#### Reference

- [Guide for working with JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) in JavaScript

Comment: Quick aside: there's no need to add the "hope it helps" message, or enquiring whether readers did not understand or need something else. Readers are expected to know this. Brevity and technical writing is preferred. (Editors will generally remove this, and your post history has 146 of them!)

Comment: Hi @halfer ! Brevity and good answer quality are not the only important features in this community. Politeness and human interactions are as important. Moreover, I consider that a vast amount of people that ask questions are inexperienced or new to the community and you can't assume what they know. I invite you to also look at the information from another perspective, from 146 answers with this text no editor has removed them. Nevertheless, thank you for your advise, I will take it into account, if you need anything let me know :D

Comment: Editors have an enormous amount of volunteer work to do, so yes, it is quite possible for chatty material or material inviting comment conversation to escape editing for years. We do not have nearly enough editors to attain the kind of technical writing [we discuss on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions).

Comment: The advice to keep things succinct is given in the Help Centre, so I think it is reasonable for us to think that readers should know this. However, experienced contributors here are aware that people don't read help material before diving in, and it is common for old hands to advocate that people re-read [ask] after seeing a contribution that doesn't meet any of the minimum guidelines.

Comment: As for the politeness angle: I have replayed that conversation (and the established community's views on it) a few hundred times in the comments, and broadly it goes like this. Be polite in real life, contributors here are in favour of politeness, we still advocate for succinctness and technical writing. Answers here are a bit like Wikipedia articles - the authors are undoubtedly nice people, but they don't put greetings at the top or thanks-for-reading at the bottom.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf - Thank you! And as someone who is new to this, I appreciate your politeness. The code mostly worked - in the `add new contact if it doesn't exist` section,  adding a phone number doesn't work, but if I run the script twice the phone number gets added. I've changed the script so that it only runs on the last row, as I only need it to pick-up new form submissions. Perhaps slightly clunky for now, but it will work until I'm more skilled and have reviewed the reference guide you provided.

Comment: Hi ! Unfortunatelly aparently adding the phone number after a contact has just been created works unconsistently and it has been reported as a bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136104507), please check the report and star it to indicate that this is also afecting you. Also please consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem. Thanks ! :D