# Array only showing last result of the loop - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

i want to get the full list of my google contacts on a JSON file, but im only getting the last value on my contacts.

What should i change? or what is the problem here?

```
function contactsJSON() {

  var contactsjson = {}
  var myContacts = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('System Group: My Contacts').getContacts();
  for (var i = 0; i < myContacts.length; i++) {

    var id = myContacts[i].getId();
    var name = myContacts[i].getFullName();

    var emailsobj = myContacts[i].getEmails();
    var email = {}
    for (var j = 0; j < emailsobj.length; j++) {
      email[emailsobj[j].getAddress().toLowerCase()] = 1;
    };

    var phonesobj = myContacts[i].getPhones();
    var phone = {}
    for (var j = 0; j < phonesobj.length; j++) {
      phone[phonesobj[j].getPhoneNumber().replace(/[_)(\s.-]/g, '')] = 1;

    };

    for (var j = 0; j < id.length; j++) {
      contactsjson = { id: id, name: name, phone: phone, email: email };
    }
  }

  contactsjson = JSON.stringify(contactsjson);
  contactsjson = JSON.parse(contactsjson);
  Logger.log(contactsjson);
  return contactsjson;
}
```

Hope you can help me,

Federico.

Comment: See how the value of `contactsjson` changes in the for loop.

Comment: I don't understand - what is the purpose of the `for (var j` loop?

Comment: @ItagakiFumihiko yes, that was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @skara9 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64960888/add-contact-if-contact-does-not-exist-under-google-contacts-with-contactsapp-ge?rq=1 i copied the code from here and edited it

Comment: @FedericoPalma You should attempt to understand how it works if you're going to copy and run it.

Comment: What i believe they do is format the value so when you can compare them with another dataset without fear of discrepancies. I'dont understand what is the = 1 part though.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.

The problem was in:

```
for (var j = 0; j < id.length; j++) {
  contactsjson = { id: id, name: name, phone: phone, email: email };
```

I changed it to:

```
 for (var j = 0; j < phonesobj.length; j++) {
  contactsjson[phonesobj[j].getPhoneNumber()] = {id: id, name: name, phone: phone, email: email}
```

and now its properly looping trough all the elements in My contacts.

Regards,

Federico.